# Away3d 4 + IOS StageWebView + Video fullscreen = View3D empty

Tags: ios, air, away3d, stagewebviewbridge

In my application (flash + away3d 4 + adobe air 3.2 for iPad) i have a View3D with some objects which are displayed correctly.
When I touch a particular object, it launches a stagewebview with this html content :

`[...]
<video id="video" controls="true" autoplay="true" width="100%" height="100%" src="video.mp4"></video> [...]`

The stagewebview is displayed fine and i can launch the video without problem, and i continue to see the View3D in the background.

But, if I switch the video to fullscreen mode with the standard ios player and then go back to windowed mode, the View3D is empty : there are no more object displayed, but they are present in memory and visible=true.

I have set a backgroundColor to the view3D, so I can see it is always on my stage, only the meshes are missing.

I suspect a colision between stage3d and the ios video player, as they both use hardware acceleration.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely related to this bug I have been having. It appears to be hit and miss on PC's but it happens on every single PC in my office so I have to assume its an overwhelming majority issue.

http://away3d.com/forum/viewthread/2188/

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately it's an AIR bug that has not been resolved yet!

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3486264